# datepicker plugin phonegap cancel button

Tags: android, jquery, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

I use the next datePicker plugin:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker

How can I recognize when a user press the "Cancel" button?:

The image of controller: http://goo.gl/YUzus

The code that I use is:

```
window.plugins.datePicker.show({                        
    date : new Date(date),
    mode : 'date',
    allowOldDates : true    
},function(selectedDate) { 
    console.log('SET button was pressed');      
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed the cancel event modifying a bit the .java plugin :
after the code

```
public void run() {
final DateSetListener dateSetListener = new DateSetListener(datePickerPlugin, callBackId);
final DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(currentCtx, dateSetListener, mYear,mMonth, mDay);
```

I added the event to trap the cancel :

```
dateDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{
    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
    datePickerPlugin.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT, ""), callBackId);}}});
```

This will set the date to "" when pressed the cancel button.
In the javascript code i managed to change the focus event to tap event as follow (I use the plugin on mobile that have TAP events:

```
 $('.nativedatepicker').bind('tap',function(event) {
            var currentField = $(this);

            console.log(currentField.val());
            var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

            if(typeof myNewDate === "number"){ myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate); }
            //myNewDate = currentField.val();

            console.log("inside native date picker " + event);

            // Same handling for iPhone and Android
            window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                date : myNewDate,
                mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
                allowOldDates : true
            }, function(returnDate) {
                console.log("ret date" + returnDate);
                if (returnDate)
                    {
                        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
                        currentField.val(returnDate);

                        // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
                        currentField.blur();
                    }
            });
        });
```

I hope can help.

Comment: I had to add import android.content.DialogInterface; to the top of the file as well

Comment: and used callbackContext.success(""); instead of datePickerPlugin.success